# VBA pasting 3 dimensional array into sheet

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

I have a 3 dimensional array (5 x 5 x 3) and I need to post (5 x 5 x 1) to Sheet1, (5 x 5 x 2) to Sheet2, (5 x 5 x 3) to Sheet3.  Because I am building this 3 dimensional array inside 3 nested for loops, I cannot use a for loop to access the (5 x 5) part of the loop.  Is there any identifier that tells excel to index all elements of an array, such as in MatLab by using (1:end, 1:end, 1)?  Basic code is below:

```
Sub practice_2()

Dim arr(1 To 5, 1 To 5, 1 To 3)
Dim a As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

    For a = 1 To 3
        For x = 1 To 5
            For y = 1 To 5
                arr(x, y, a) = x * y
            Next
        Next

        Sheets(a).Select
        'Following line is where I want to access the (5 x 5 x 1) array
        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 5)) = arr
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not much you can do directly with a 3-D array in Excel. However, VBA Variants are pretty flexible. You could get what you want by using a 1-D array that contains 2-D arrays instead of a 3-D array:

```
Dim arr(1 To 3)

Dim a As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

For a = 1 To 3
    ReDim inner(1 To 5, 1 To 5)

    'don't worry...makes a copy
    arr(a) = inner

    For x = 1 To 5
        For y = 1 To 5
            arr(a)(x, y) = a * x * y
        Next
    Next

    Sheets(a).Select

    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 5)) = arr(a)
Next
```

(In answer to your specific question about array syntax, the answer is "no".)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub PasteThreeDemensionalArray()

    'Declare Array
    Dim ArrA(19, 2) As Integer
    'Declare & Set Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'NOTE:  To test, add data to the first 20 rows of Columns A, B, and C
    'Read Data into Array
    For x = 1 To 20
        ArrA(x - 1, 0) = ws1.Cells(x, 1)
        ArrA(x - 1, 1) = ws1.Cells(x, 2)
        ArrA(x - 1, 2) = ws1.Cells(x, 3)
    Next
    'A single WorksheetFunction.Transpose will add your data horizontally
    ws1.Range("E1:X3") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrA)
    'A double WorksheetFunction.Transpose will add your data vertically
    ws1.Range("Z1:AB20") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrA))
End Sub
```