# Populating VBA dynamic arrays

Tags: arrays, vba

The following code gives me error 9 "subscript out of range". I meant to declare a dynamic array so that the dimension changes as I add elements to it. Do I have to create a "spot" on the array before I store something in it like in JS?

```
Sub test_array()
    Dim test() As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 3
        test(i) = 3 + i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

in your for loop use a Redim on the array like here:

```
For i = 0 to 3
  ReDim Preserve test(i)
  test(i) = 3 + i
Next i
```

Comment: Why would you do it *in* the loop? `ReDim`, and especially when you add `Preserve`, is a potential performance killer. You know how many times the loop is going to iterate, so definitely do it outside of the loop. Then you're only resizing the array once, and you don't need the `Preserve`.

Comment: @CodyGray You are absolutely right if the final array size is already defined on entering the loop. Putting the Redim inside of the loop would be a performance killer. However, I assumed that the size of the array is not determined on entering the loop. Otherwise the whole sample doesn't make sense at all...

Comment: It *has* to be defined upon entering the loop. You have to define the range of the loop. Even if it's a variable rather than a constant like `3`, you're still specifying an upper-bound in the `For` statement. Use that to dynamically initialize the size of the array.

Comment: You could leave the array using "Exit For"

Comment: Maybe this solution is not very nice regarding optimalisation, but if you would not know the size in front - e.g. doing a while loop with some condition - then this may be the easiest solution

Comment: @CodyGray Also this is (probably) only solution, if you using for each, to iterate some items, which count is unknown.

Comment: "For each" works on collections which generally have a .count property. However the question and answer are still valid for various scenarios, such as Do While loops and where adding to the array is conditional within the For loop based on an If statement.

Answer (score 26):

As Cody and Brett mentioned, you could reduce VBA slowdown with sensible use of `Redim Preserve`.  Brett suggested `Mod` to do this.

You can also use a user defined `Type` and `Sub` to do this.  Consider my code below:

```
Public Type dsIntArrayType
   eElems() As Integer
   eSize As Integer
End Type

Public Sub PushBackIntArray( _
    ByRef dsIntArray As dsIntArrayType, _
    ByVal intValue As Integer)

    With dsIntArray
    If UBound(.eElems) < (.eSize + 1) Then
        ReDim Preserve .eElems(.eSize * 2 + 1)
    End If
    .eSize = .eSize + 1
    .eElems(.eSize) = intValue
    End With

End Sub
```

This calls `ReDim Preserve` only when the size has doubled.  The member variable `eSize` keeps track of the actual data size of `eElems`.  This approach has helped me improve performance when final array length is not known until run time.

Hope this helps others too.

Comment: yes! wanted to offer an alternative for other readers as well.  i realize the op has accepted the previous answer already.  thanks.

Comment: Well then here's a +1 for you, interesting alternative! :)

Comment: +1. this is similar to how dynamic arrays are implemented in C++ standard library.  I would make push_back a method and the type a class, for encapsulation purposes.

Comment: I got a subscript out of range error at `UBound(.eElems)` when calling `PushBackIntArray` for the first time... any thoughts?

Comment: how do you call the functions on a 2D array to resize its first dimension dynamically? Also `.esize` does not give the exact size of the dimensioned array? It is not working for me, if i pass an `Arr =Array(1 to 1)` or `Arr = Array(1 to 1, 1 to 1)`.

Answer (score 25):

Yes, you're looking for the `ReDim` statement, which dynamically allocates the required amount of space in the array.

The following statement

```
Dim MyArray()
```

declares an array without dimensions, so the compiler doesn't know how big it is and can't store anything inside of it.

But you can use the `ReDim` statement to resize the array:

```
ReDim MyArray(0 To 3)
```

And if you need to resize the array while *preserving* its contents, you can use the `Preserve` keyword along with the `ReDim` statement:

```
ReDim Preserve MyArray(0 To 3)
```

But do note that both `ReDim` and particularly `ReDim Preserve` have a heavy performance cost. Try to avoid doing this over and over in a loop if at all possible; your users will thank you.

---

However, in the simple example shown in your question (if it's not just a throwaway sample), you don't need `ReDim` at all. Just declare the array with explicit dimensions:

```
Dim MyArray(0 To 3)
```

Comment: +1 though I would add that the lower bound can and in my opinion should be specified explicitly: `ReDim MyArray(0 To 3)`

Comment: @Jean: That's good advice. A lot of people are bitten by the fact that VB(A) supports lower bounds other than 0. Being explicit is always good practice.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to Cody's useful comments it is worth noting that at times you won't know how big your array should be. The two options in this situation are

1. Creating an array big enough to handle anything you think will be thrown at it
2. *Sensible* use of `Redim Preserve`

The code below provides an example of a routine that will dimension `myArray` in line with the `lngSize` variable, then add additional elements (equal to the initial array size) by use of a `Mod` test whenever the upper bound is about to be exceeded

```
Option Base 1

Sub ArraySample()
    Dim myArray() As String
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    Dim lngSize As Long

    lngSize = 10
    ReDim myArray(1 To lngSize)

    For lngCnt = 1 To lngSize*5
        If lngCnt Mod lngSize = 0 Then ReDim Preserve myArray(1 To UBound(myArray) + lngSize)
        myArray(lngCnt) = "I am record number " & lngCnt
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 13):

I see many (all) posts above relying on `LBound`/`UBound` calls upon yet potentially uninitialized VBA dynamic array, what causes application's inevitable death ...

Erratic code:

`Dim x As Long
    Dim arr1() As SomeType
    ... 
    x = UBound(arr1) 'crashes`

Correct code:

`Dim x As Long
    Dim arr1() As SomeType
    ...
    ReDim Preserve arr1(0 To 0)
    ...
    x = UBound(arr1)`

... i.e. any code where `Dim arr1()` is followed immediatelly by `LBound(arr1)`/`UBound(arr1)` calls without `ReDim arr1(...)` in between, crashes. The roundabout is to employ an `On Error Resume Next` and check the `Err.Number` right after the `LBound(arr1)`/`UBound(arr1)` call - it should be 0 if the array is initialized, otherwise non-zero. As there is some VBA built-in misbehavior, the further check of array's limits is needed. Detailed explanation may everybody read at [Chip Pearson's website](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm) (which should be celebrated as a *Mankind Treasure Of VBA Wisdom* ...)

Heh, that's my first post, believe it is legible.

Comment: That comment re all coded above relying on ubound/lbound is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

**A class-based approach with `BetterArray`**
In 2013, Ioannis commented that you could create a class to manage array resizing in chunks.  An implementation with many other features—sorting, slicing, filtering, and conversion, to name a few—can now be found here: https://senipah.github.io/VBA-Better-Array/ (I am not connected to the project). A page on its [capacity](https://senipah.github.io/VBA-Better-Array/api/properties/capacity/Capacity.html) property explains the internal doubling process.  More generally:

> Stored in a single .cls file, the BetterArray class can easily be
> imported into any new or existing VBA project. It’s written in pure
> VBA and doesn’t use any external dependencies. As such, it should work
> in any application that supports VBA scripting across both Windows and
> Mac operating systems.

In other words, you simply download the class module (a single .cls file, linked [here](https://senipah.github.io/VBA-Better-Array/home/installation.html)), drag it into your project<sup>*</sup>, and from there it’s available like a collection or any other object to create. Here I use it to get the contents of the current directory:

```
Sub DemoBetterArray()

    Dim ba As BetterArray, tempDir As String, basicArray As Variant
    Set ba = New BetterArray
    tempDir = Dir("")
    Do While tempDir <> ""
        ba.Push tempDir 'I set no bounds, but I'm adding an element
        tempDir = Dir()
    Loop
    basicArray = ba.Items 'See results in a traditional array
    
End Sub
```

For this example, you could do similar with an `ArrayList`, generally available on Windows via .NET (but apparently [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-6.0) in .NET).  See a [summary](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/).  In any case, there are major differences between these objects you could explore.  For adding 1,000,000 integers, I found BetterArray to be several times faster than an ArrayList.

A tip for using the BetterArray documentation: While the page on examples is currently blank, the pages on methods (listed [here](https://senipah.github.io/VBA-Better-Array/api/methods/)) give many helpful examples of what the class can do in addition to expanding efficiently.

**Expansion via Error Handling**
Another possibility not yet discussed is to use error handling. The approach is demonstrated by Bruce McKinney in *Hardcore Visual Basic, 2nd Edition* (1997). The function below uses this idea.

```
Sub VectorFill(sourceVector As Variant, Index As Long, Value As Variant)
'Fills a 1d array at a specified index and increases the UBound if needed (by doubling it).
'Trim unneeded space separately with ReDim Preserve.

    Const resizeMultiplier As Integer = 2
    
    'With this statement, an out of bounds error will trigger a resize
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
    sourceVector(Index) = Value
    Exit Sub
    
'ErrorHandling used to resize array in chunks
ErrorHandling:
    newBound = (UBound(sourceVector) + 1) * resizeMultiplier '+1 helps with initial 0
    ReDim Preserve sourceVector(newBound)
    Resume 'New space is available, so go back and try again

End Sub
```

The above function can be used as follows:

```
Sub DemoVectorFill()

    Dim dirContents() As Variant, i As Long
    ReDim dirContents(0)
    dirContent = Dir("")
    Do While dirContent <> ""
        VectorFill dirContents, i, dirContent
        dirContent = Dir
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    ReDim Preserve dirContents(i - 1)

End Sub
```

With this approach, you don't have to check capacity at each iteration, and leverage the error when it occurs.  On my tests it is not faster than making that check (it’s a hair slower), but as sizes increase either way is much faster than ReDim Preserve at each iteration.

---

<sup><sup>*</sup>If you try to copy and paste the BetterArray code into a class module, this will not entirely work.  Class modules have some code that is hidden in the VBA editor, and won't be copied via copy paste.  The two options are to drag the .cls file into the Project pane or use **File** --> **Import File**.</sup>