# excel 2003 vba.. writing arraylist

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create `ArrayList` of Class like in Java, in Visual Basic Excel 2003.

Java

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setName("tom");
employees.add(employee);
```

VB

```
Dim resultList As New Collection    
Dim Manager As Employee
Manager.Name = "df"    
resultList.Add ("rr") 'correct
resultList.Add (Manager) 'error
```

But this gives the following error:

> only user-define types defined in public object modules can be coerced
>   to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions

Answer (score 1):

There is no type information associated with a UDT so it can't be added to a collection as there is no way to reliably convert to/from a variant as the number & types of its members is unknown.

You can either replace the `Employee` Type with a Class or as you don't appear to be using a key, a typed array: `arr() as Employee`

Comment: with arr() I need to define array size. I do not know the array size. Can't arraylist/list be used?

Comment: No, collections hold variants and a UDT cannot be converted to such. Arrays do *not* need to be defined with a fixed size, you can make them dynamic and resize as needed; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850984/populating-vba-dynamic-arrays