# Not able to redim 2 dimension array Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I had an 2 dimension array, (1 to 406, 1 to 8)

when I try to redim and perserve the value

```
 ReDim Preserve arr(1 To UBound(arr()) + 1, 1 To 8)
```

it pop out error Subscript out of range, what actually Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only ReDim Preserve the last dimension in a multidimensional array with VBA, which is a great feature.

There are some workarounds to this issue described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992717/how-can-i-redim-preserve-a-2d-array-in-excel-2007-vba-so-that-i-can-add-rows) answer.

Comment: ouch, guess thats the only solution for this

Comment: Link to other SO posts are not answers. You should have ideally marked this question as duplicate rather than re-answering it :)